# cfqueryparam pass in list from input checkbox

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfqueryparam

I have a input checkbox field where user can select multiple checkboxes in a form, and depending on what they select, it will create a string of id's like 10,14,35,47, and that will be submitted to the database.  I can get this submitted if I just submit it directly like below:

```
user_job_type_id="#form.user_job_type_id#",
```

But, if I try and wrap that in a cfqueryparam, which I would rather do to make it more secure, I get an error, regardless of what I do.  Whether I set it to a list true or false, varchar, integer, everything throws an error like cfqueryparam doesnt accept the list.

For example, below will not work

```
user_job_type_id=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#form.user_job_type_id#" list="Yes"/>,
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: If you're trying to search for multiple id's, the sql syntax is incorrect. The equals `=` operator only compares single values.  For multiple values, use `IN (...)`. i.e. `where user_job_type_id IN ( <cfqueryparam list ....> )`.  See your dbms documentation for more details.

Answer (score 6):

As @SOS mentioned, you need to use an `IN` statement when checking against a list of values in parenthesis. In addition, since the values are all integers, make sure to specify the correct `cfsqltype`. This ensures the correct date type check for each element in the list.

Wrong:

```
user_job_type_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#form.user_job_type_id#" list="Yes"/>,
```

Better:

```
user_job_type_id IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#form.user_job_type_id#" list="Yes"/>),
```

Best:

```
user_job_type_id IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#form.user_job_type_id#" list="Yes"/>),
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to insert to the database though, not query. So this would be an example: 
```
    update user_job
    set user_job_type_id=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" 
    value="#form.user_job_type_id#" list="Yes"/>
    where user_job_id= #form.user_job_id#
```
This throws an error from the cfqueryparam usage. If I do not use cfqueryparam and do the below, it works fine, although Id rather use the cfqueryparam if possible:
   ``` update user_job
    set user_job_type_id=user_job_type_id="#form.user_job_type_id#"
    where user_job_id= #form.user_job_id#```

Comment: Do you have a way to associate the items in #form.user_job_type_id# with the items in #form.user_job_id#? Then loop over the list to do your insert.

Comment: The list is stored in a single cell in the database as a comma separated list.  So it would end up like '49,56,87' for example.  I cant figure out why cfqueryparam doesn't like the comma separated list.

Comment: In that case, nix the list attribute and just insert it as a string. The list attribute is more for `where x in ()` clauses.